# get reference to methods object, when method called from other class (javascript)

Tags: javascript, events, reference

I want to call a method from an object through an event handler from callObject. But if I call the method object.setX() from inside another class, the reference to "this" is lost. How can i still reference the object, the method was constructed in?

```
var object = {

    init: function () {
        this.x = 0;
    },

    setX: function (value) {
        $('body').append('got called</br>');
        this.x = value;
    },

    printX: function () {
        $('body').append('x: ' + this.x + '</br>');
    }
}

var callObject = {

    call: function (func) {
        func(3);
    }
}

object.init();
callObject.call(object.setX);
object.printX();
object.setX(5);
object.printX();
```

the result from this would be:

> got called
>
> x: 0
>
> got called
>
> x: 5

here is the jfiddle script: http://jsfiddle.net/mqDa6/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqDa6/3/), using [apply method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (same can be achieved using [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [jQuery.proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)) to maintain correct scope:

```
var callObject = {

    call: function(func) {
        // Needs scope object as first parameter.
        func.apply(object, [3]);
    }
}
```

This way, by using any of these methods, we are able to specify what scope our function should resolve to.

[Here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2265-Changing-The-Execution-Context-Of-JavaScript-Functions-Using-Call-And-Apply-.htm) is a great article giving more details on this aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) Like this:

```
callObject.call(object.setX.bind(object));
```

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Comment: thanks! both answers are basicly the same, an they both work.